# Add data to JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json

With a form, I want to add data to my JSON file. How can I do that ? Do I need to recreate a JSON file or can I add data to my existing JSON file ?

The $http.post doesn't work so it's a bad use of it or I need to replace it ?

**HTML File**

```
<body ng-app='app'>      
    <div ng-init="getData()" ng-controller="listController">
        <ul ng-repeat="detail in details">
            <li>
                <a href="{{detail.url}}">{{detail.url}}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                {{detail.description}}
            </li>
            <li>
                {{detail.author}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form method=POST ng-submit="submit()">
            <label for="lien">Lien :
                <input type="url" id="lien" ng-model="detail.url" placeholder="http://"/>
            </label>
            {{detail.url}}
            <br><br>
            <label for="description">Description :
                <textarea id="description" ng-model="detail.description"></textarea>
            </label>
            {{detail.description}}
            <br><br>
            <label for="auteur">Auteur :
                <input type="text" id="auteur" ng-model="detail.author"></input>
            </label>
            {{detail.author}}
            <p>{{detail}}</p>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            <p>{{details}}</p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JS File**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("listController", ["$scope","$http",
function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.getData = function()
    {
        $http.get('youtube.json').then(function (response){
            $scope.details  = response.data;    
        });
    };
    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        $scope.details.push($scope.detail);
        $http.post('youtube.json', $scope.details);
    }
}]);
```

**JSON File**

```
[
    {
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1NIJjTYq6U",
        "author": "Grafikart.fr",
        "description": "Salut tout le monde"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOuKMuaGJ54&list=PLjwdMgw5TTLUDlJyx4yIPQjoI-w-7Zs1r",
        "author": "Grafikart.fr",
        "description": "Les directives"
    }
]
```

Comment: You'll need some server side logic to persist the changes.

Comment: You should do that with PHP on your server. Check out the `file_put_contents()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is statically served on a server, and that is why you can call `$http.get('youtube.json')` and have access to it. So, the server provides a URL for you to access it. To actually write to it, you still need a server who will handle the request, and write to the file (if its nodejs with the 'fs' module). Other than that, you cannot access the file system from web :) I hope this helps clarify things.